# Openfire server: authenticate with a token instead of username/password

Tags: authentication, xmpp, openfire

Is there any built-in way or a plugin for token-based authentication instead of a standard username/password entering? So that a user would be able to quit the client application (web-, java-based, whatever) and get back again without having to re-enter the password each time.

I know, we can extend and compile our own Authentication Provider in Openfire. But maybe there is a ready solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't authenticate without username and password. It is compulsory for login. And once you success authenticate no need to enter username and password again. Just you have to store username and password very first time and every time on app launch you have to pass that username and password for authenticate.

Comment: well, it's not secure to store the password in the client side (cookies, other local storage, whatever)

Comment: Ok then store username and password with encrypted. So now it will be secure.

Comment: Hi @Parthpatel1105, I don't think we could store an encrypted password as well. Since we need plain password to login.